# Limitations on mongodb Polygon

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to insert a Polygon on a mongodb document

```
polygons: { 
    type: "Polygon", 
    coordinates: [ 
        [ 
            [ -104.6093679, 50.449794 ], 
            [ -104.6093679, 50.449794 ],
            [ -104.6093863, 50.449794 ], 
            [ -104.6093863, 50.449794 ], 
            [ -104.6093679, 50.449794 ] 
        ] 
    ] 
}
```

But mongodb throws this exception: "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?" I also checked the correctness of index and verified that with the same structure but different data, insert works well. My question is: are there some limitations on Polygon area that mongodb can manage?

Comment: That's not a polygon - it's a point. It's valid GeoJSON (well, with "'s around the keys), but that doesn't mean it encodes a valid polygon. MongoDB can't process it as a polygon because it's not really a polygon.